# Checkout process rest api

Tags: magento2, cart, rest-api

/rest/V1/carts/:cartid/payment-information code is not working. The request does not match any route. Please suggest something.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

POST /V1/guest-carts/:cartId/payment-information

GET /V1/guest-carts/:cartId/payment-information

POST /V1/carts/mine/payment-information

GET /V1/carts/mine/payment-information

POST /V1/guest-carts/:cartId/set-payment-information

POST /V1/carts/mine/set-payment-information

Link has all endpoints of the REST.

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/rest/list.html